# How to open the actual folder a library subfolder refers to?

Tags: windows-libraries

When I open a library subfolder in explorer, it is displayed as subfolder of that library. However, I want to open the actual subfolder without explorer remembering I got there via a library (e.g. the customization feature is otherwise not available). How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I found so far is copy-pasting the path from the address bar (which is expanded correctly on clicking) and pasting it into a *different* explorer window or the start menu's text field. But that is tedious if repeated often, and spams my [ClipX](http://bluemars.org/clipx/) clipboard history.

Answer (score 0):

put the following line in a .bat file and run it from the folder you want to open:

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe %~dp0
```

this opens explorer in batch file location.

Comment: hm, not exactly effortless I am afraid to say. But that brings me to the idea of simply adding a new "Open" option to the `folder` type...

Comment: keep the batch file in clipx :)

Comment: Indeed interesting suggestion, especially with its `sticky` plugin :D